# Working with Interfaces for backward compatibitly

Tags: c#, dll, interface

I have a design question. I have following interface in my project -

```
interface ITest
{
    void SayHello();
}
```

And it is implemented by this class by each client -

```
class TestImpl : ITest
{
    public void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Now this interface has been in use for quite some time, there are a lot of clients that use this code.

```
class LibraryClass
{
    private ITest test;

    public void initialize(ITest t)
    {
        test = t;
    }

    public void Call()
    {
        test.SayHello();
        LibraryClass2 l2 = new LibraryClass2();
        l2.SayHelloAgain(test);
    }
}

class LibraryClass2
{
    public void SayHelloAgain(ITest test)
    {
        test.SayHello();
    }
}


class Client
{
    private ITest test;

    public void Client2Method()
    {
        LibraryClass l = new LibraryClass();
        l.initialize(new TestImpl1);
        l.Call();
    }
}
```

Now, I want to change the way the SayHello was written. I want to pass the name as an argument to the function and return the user response, it should look something like this -

```
string SayHello(string name);
```

I do not want to change the API provided in the library. How can I do this so that I keep the code backward compatible as well as support new call?

EDIT: Updated the code to fix reflect the actual problem I am facing.

Thanks

Comment: If you control the code for the interface then simply add the method string SayHello(string name); to ITest.

Comment: No I dont . Each client has its own implementation of interface

Comment: That makes it very different though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new interface, `ITest2` containing the new method, ask your users to start implementing it. Mark `ITest` as obsolete so they get a warning.

Implement two overloads of `Initialize`, one taking `ITest` and the other taking `ITest2`. Change your methods to act accordingly if `test` or `test2` is not null.

```
 test?.SayHello();
 string result = test2?.SayHello("some string");
```

Not great, but probably the best you can do given the constraints you listed.